# Converting powers of 3 into powers of 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

I'm stuck on a problem. I have a term $3^m$ where $m$ is an integer $> 0$. and I want to represent it as $2^m + a$ however I don't want to keep the $a$. I am looking for a formula to represent $a$ using numbers and the variable $m$. Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't $a=3^m-2^m$ good enough?  I'm not clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I am trying to remove all powers of 3. And only keep powers of 2.

Comment: What about $3 = 2^{\log_2 3}$?

Comment: What if its $3^7$?

Comment: $3^7 = 2^{7\log_2{3}}$

Comment: Can you please give a couple of examples?  For example, say $m=1$; what are you looking for in that case?  And say $m=2$; what are you looking for then?

Comment: If m=1, then its $3^1 = 2^1 + 1$, if $m=2$ then its $3^2 = 2^2 + 5$, etc
so $m=1$, we find $1$, then $m=2$ we find $5$, etc...

Comment: I think what everyone's trying to say is that $3^m = 2^{\left( m \frac{log{3}}{log{2}} \right)}$

Comment: For $m=5$ then $a=243-32=211$  How do you want to represent this?  You say you want to get rid of the powers of $3$ and not keep $a$.

Comment: For $2^m = 3^n + a$ it should be enough to take the floor of the logarithm base 3 of $2^m$ as $n$.

Comment: if m=5, then a should be 211. The problem I was searching for was a formula to represent 211, so it could be like with summations or logs or something and the only variable can be m.

Comment: If $3^m=2^m+a$ then $a=3^m-2^m$. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is more a collection of information than a formula.  It seems tough to get an elementary function on this.*

*We can get a generating function for this.*

There's a lot of information on this [on Sloan's Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, A001047](http://oeis.org/A001047).

It looks like you have:

$$3^m = 2^m + a$$

Also, I believe you want to represent $a$ as a formula of $m$.

This can be done by a generating function.  The way this works is that we use induction.  We consider what we'd get with $3^{m-1}$, and then calculate what we'd get with $3^m$.

First, we want to figure out the difference between $3^m$ and $2^m$.  We realize that we can visualize $3^m$ as a "hypercube"; that is, an $m$-dimensional cube with sides of length 3.  Now $2^m$ is an $m$ dimensional cube with sides of length 2.  So the difference between the larger cube and the smaller cube is adding length one to each side of the smaller cube.

We do this by first adding $3^{m-1}$.  This gives us part of what we need.  Then we can add twice the previous case (remember, we're doing this by induction).  That will give us the required difference.

Now, we can construct a generating function to give us the answer.  If you're interested in a very, very simple introduction, you can [download a free copy of Wilf's Generatingfunctionology here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

**THE GENERATING FUNCTION**

We state this as recursively as:

$$a_{m+1} = 2 a_m + 3^{m-1}$$

This translates into the generating function:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty{a_{m+1}x^m} &= 2 \cdot \sum_{m=1}^\infty{a_{m}x^m} + \frac{3}{(1-3x)} \\
\frac{A(m)-1}{x} &= 2A(m) + \frac{3}{(1-3x)}\\
A(m) &= \frac{1}{1-5x+6}
\end{align}
$$

The series proceeds like:

$$1, 5x, 19x^2, 65x^3, 211x^4, \dots$$

Answer (score 2):

$3^m=(2+1)^m=1+\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{m!}{(m-i)! i!}2^i$

I guess you can factor out the 2's if you want.